# Concepts, use and testing Cloud Datastore in local

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm really confused with the way to try Datastore in local. Please, give me a minute to explain.

I'm developing a app composed to few microservices like a only gae app. In a  parte of the app, I use the datastore. So when I run my app, I use the development server and when I save something in the datastore calling some method I can see perfectly the entity in the gae's admin web portal.

Well, now, instead of calling directly to ndb library and his methods I've built a  small library over ndb to abstract his functionallity, then I can call insertUser() instead of work directly with ndb. So, the problems appear when I try test this small library that I built (I've written a test.py file to do this).
At first, I thought  that this does not  can work because this test was executing without the deveserver running. After I searched info about how simulated the datastore in the local and I found this, but after I found too the unittest in local with the stubs, and now I don't understand nothing.

I've tried both ([gcloud datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) and [stub with unittest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting))  and I don't get  do simple example:
I want test that a entity is saved in Datastore and after I want test that I can read this entity

I suppose that [dev_server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server#Python_Running_the_development_web_server) (in SDK) emulate the datastore (because I can see the list of my entities there), but then, why use the datastore emulator in local dev?, and then, why is necesary uses the stub to datastore if we have a datastore emulator to do all test that I want? I don't understand.

I understand that maybe my question is more of concepts than code but I need understand really right how is the best way to work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I solved and understood my problem. If I were working with other system that I want connect to Cloud Datastore, I would need  use the "emulator". But isn't my case. So, I need use the stubs with unittest because there are not a simple way (I think is imposible) to do this with the dev_server (when he is running).
But i found two mainly problems:

The first, the way to import google_appengine libraries, because in the documentation isn't very clear, (in my view), finally searching user opinions I found that "my solution was something like this":

```
sys.path.insert(1, '../../../../google_appengine')

if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
```

The second was that when I execute a test (one of few of I had) the next unittest failed, for example, when in the first unittest, I save the data and in the second I test if the data is saved correctly with a read method.

When I initialized `datastore_v3_stub` I use `save_changes=True` to specify that I want the changes be permanent, but when I use it, don't work and I see that the changes maybe don't be saved.

After, I found in the tesbed docs the param datastore_file, when I used this and specify a file where save *temporarily* the database,  all tests began to work fine.

```
self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(enable=True, save_changes=True, datastore_file='./dbFile')
```

Besides, I added a final condition (unittest library) to delete this file, so, I erase the file when the test ends. (Avoiding errors in the next execution).

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(self):
    """
    Elimina el fichero de la bd temporal tras la ejecución de todos los tests.
    """
    os.remove('./dbFile')
```

I think that GAE and all Google Cloud Platform is a very good solution to develop fast apps but I think too that they need revise and extend his docs, specially to no-experts programmers (like me).
I hope that this solution maybe help someone, if you think that I have some error please comment it.